# Kivy Event Bind() returns only self: callback() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, kivy

This is a dummy looping program that I created, It should create one button, clicking the button should create a new button with the same name.

It fails after the second button click, the event does not pass the instance object anymore.

self.frame is referring to the .kv file
First File

```
#run.py
import view

class UserInterface(BoxLayout):

    self.V = view.View()
    def callback(self, instance):
        print "Instance Object: ", instance
        if instance.id == "Home":

            activeView = self.V.home()
            # Clear children before instating new view
            self.frame.clear_widgets()
            self.frame.add_widget(activeView)
```

Second File

```
#view.py
from run import UserInterface

class View():
    def home(self):
        nav_panel = BoxLayout(orientation= "vertical", id="navPanel")
        btn = Button(text="Normal binding to event", id="Home")
        btn.bind(on_press=UserInterface.callback)
        nav_panel.add_widget(btn)
    return btn
```

#### Output:

```
Instance Object: <kivy.uix.button.Button object at 0x709fac00>
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
TypeError: callback() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

The 1 argument is "self"
Can you see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The on_press() callback takes only one argument, which is the button instance, not the UserInterface instance. So callback() should only take one argument.

Comment: Also, your `self.V = view.View()` is illegal since it is outside any method, and `self` is undefined there. I suspect that should be in a `build()` or `__init__()` method.

Comment: Thank you, that puts me in the right direction. Also, __init__() should be there yes.